# Recommended hosting for PostGIS app

Tags: php, postgresql, hosting, postgis

I've developed an **PHP** + **PostGIS** app and I need to host it somewhere.
Can anyone recomend me a web **hosting** that sopport Postgres + PostGIS databases?
I found some places to host the app, but I would like to read about **your experiences**.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've recently discovered Railway, a pay-what-you-use hoster that offers managed Postgres (externally accessible) with PostGIS enabled. It looks like it could be a good fit for my low usage application. Other modern providers like Render and Fly may work well too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford ~49 eur per month for your application, then I would recommend using a service like this: http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_rootserver/eq4

currently we use 8 of them, and they seem quite cheap (for a dedicated server) and reliable.
and you can install whatever you want on them including PostGIS : )

Answer (score 4):

Here are some useful weblinks:

'Official' list for PostgreSQL hosting: http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_hosting/

Hosting specifically with PostGIS:
* MyGeoCloud: http://beta.mygeocloud.com/
* CartoDB: http://cartodb.com/

Yours, S.

Answer (score 1):

I have several of these [MediaTemple Servers](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/ve/) (if you pay per year, it's barely 20$/mo for the starting config) and it worked perfectty so far, plus you can upgrade/downgrade the config (storage space and RAM) in literally 5 minutes. I installed pg 9.1 beta and postgis 1.5.3 on them and it works just fine.

But my favorite feature is by far the "instant snapshot" backups where it saves a snapshot of the whole system (database state, filesystem, runnig processes) and can restore it in a 2-3 minutes which is very useful for you're finetuning your server because even if you completely break everything, you still have a panic button to restore everything to a working state.

I haven't tested it yet, however [EnterpriseDB's new Cloud tools](http://www.enterprisedb.com/solutions/postgres-plus-cloud-computing) could make [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/) an interesting option (I only use [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/en/s3/) for the daily backups currently).